# discord bot coding function calls

Tags: function, discord.py

A good portion of the code right now is me trying to figure out what I am doing wrong, so I am printing a few things here and there.

My goal:

- Retrieve number of messages in a specific discord channel, and delete any new messages that exceed the limit of 10 (haven't implemented deletion yet)
- I want this to be an event (currently a command for testing) that is called whenever a member tries to post a message in said channel
- Planning on using message.channel when I swap to an on_messege event, and hopefully I can figure it all out from there...
- The msg counter function does work when I call it just using !numMsg (with both ctx and when I add the channel name myself i.e. !numMsg channel-name)

```
# delete new messages if 10 already exist in channel
@bot.command(name = 'test')
async def test(ctx):
    print('in here')
    print(ctx.channel.id)
    num = await message_count(ctx.channel)
    await ctx.send(num)

# msg counter
@bot.command(name = 'numMsg')
async def message_count(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel=None):
    print('in here 2')
    print(channel)
    channel = channel or ctx.channel
    count = 0
    async for _ in channel.history(limit=None):
        count += 1
    return count
    #await ctx.send(count)
    #await ctx.send("There were {} messages in {}".format(count, channel.mention))
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output]

Here is how I change the code slightly to confirm the function itself works:

```
# msg counter
@bot.command(name = 'numMsg')
async def message_count(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel=None):
    print('in here 2')
    print(channel)
    channel = channel or ctx.channel
    count = 0
    async for _ in channel.history(limit=None):
        count += 1
    #return count
    await ctx.send(count)
    #await ctx.send("There were {} messages in {}".format(count, channel.mention))
```

[image: Output calling function directly]

[image: Output calling function directly 2]

Comment: What's the problem ? So far, you just sent your code and showed that it was working, what have you tried that triggers an error ?

Comment: @Mr_Spaar it doesn't work as intended; look at the first output for example where it reads "None" even though I passed in ctx.channel

If I can get that to work correctly, then it might all actually work as I want

Also, the bot doesn't do anything even though I have the line "await ctx.send(num)", which tells me something went wrong somewhere (probably where it's reading 'None' as the channel)